# Draw border around content of UIImageView

Tags: ios, xcode, image, uiimageview, draw

I've a UIImageView with a image with is a car with a transparent background:

[image]

And I want to draw a border around the car:

[image]

How can I reach this effect?

At the moment, I've tested CoreGraphics in this way, but without good results:

```
    // load the image
    UIImage *img = carImage;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(img.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [[UIColor redColor] setFill];
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, img.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeNormal);
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, img.size.width * 1.1, img.size.height*1.1);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, img.CGImage);

    CGContextClipToMask(context, rect, img.CGImage);
    CGContextAddRect(context, rect);
    CGContextDrawPath(context,kCGPathFill);

    // generate a new UIImage from the graphics context we drew onto
    UIImage *coloredImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Any help? Thanks.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's what I did:

I did it in **Swift** just to check it in **playgrounds**, think you can translate it to **Objective-C** easily:

```
import UIKit

func drawOutlie(#image:UIImage, color:UIColor) -> UIImage
{
  var newImageKoef:CGFloat = 1.08
  
  var outlinedImageRect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: image.size.width * newImageKoef, height: image.size.height * newImageKoef)
  
  var imageRect = CGRect(x: image.size.width * (newImageKoef - 1) * 0.5, y: image.size.height * (newImageKoef - 1) * 0.5, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height)
  
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(outlinedImageRect.size, false, newImageKoef)
  
  image.drawInRect(outlinedImageRect)
  
  var context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
  CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeSourceIn)
  
  CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, color.CGColor)
  CGContextFillRect(context, outlinedImageRect)
  image.drawInRect(imageRect)
  
  var newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
  UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
  
  return newImage
  
}

var imageIn = UIImage(named: "158jM")

var imageOut = drawOutlie(image: imageIn, UIColor.redColor())
```

So how does it work?

1. We create clean context (aka canvas) with a bit bigger size then original image (for outline)
2. We draw our image on whole canvas
3. We fill that image with color
4. We draw smaller image on top

You can change outline size changing this property : `var newImageKoef:CGFloat = 1.08`

Here's a result that I had in playgrounds

[image: image description here]

**Swift 5:**

```
extension UIImage {
    
    func drawOutline(imageKeof: CGFloat = 0.2, color: UIColor = .white)-> UIImage? {
        let outlinedImageRect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: size.width * imageKeof, height: size.height * imageKeof)
        let imageRect = CGRect(x: self.size.width * (imageKeof - 1) * 0.5, y: self.size.height * (imageKeof - 1) * 0.5, width: size.width, height: size.height)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(outlinedImageRect.size, false, imageKeof)
        draw(in: outlinedImageRect)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        context!.setBlendMode(.sourceIn)
        context!.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
        context!.fill(outlinedImageRect)
        draw(in: imageRect)
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return newImage
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm having trouble getting the same exact result with this line of code. I've converted to Swift 5. The border is not aligned to the image.

Comment: bad solution, Since it's drawing the same image with scaling, which results in inhomogeneous stroke

Comment: This solution is perfect, https://stackoverflow.com/a/61413701/1599713

Comment: This did not create an equal border around all parts of the image.

Answer (score 6):

haawa answer for **Swift 5**

```
extension UIImage {
    func drawOutlie(imageKeof: CGFloat = 1.01, color: UIColor) -> UIImage? {

        let outlinedImageRect = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0,
                                   width: size.width * imageKeof,
                                   height: size.height * imageKeof)

        let imageRect = CGRect(x: size.width * (imageKeof - 1) * 0.5,
                           y: size.height * (imageKeof - 1) * 0.5,
                           width: size.width,
                           height: size.height)

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(outlinedImageRect.size, false, imageKeof)

        draw(in: outlinedImageRect)

        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {return nil}
        context.setBlendMode(.sourceIn)
        context.setFillColor(color.cgColor)
        context.fill(outlinedImageRect)
        draw(in: imageRect)

        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        return newImage
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This approach is a little bit different but more simple.

```
imageView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
imageView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
imageView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
imageView.layer.shadowRadius = 10.0
imageView.clipsToBounds = false
```

Comment: This is not the solution OP asked for.