# Add border to non-square UIImage

Tags: ios, uiimage, border

I try to add border around non-square png image with `layer.borderColor` and `CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor` but this result in square border around image not around the real image.

Is there a way to do this ?

Comment: Are you setting image in a UIImageView or drawing it?

Comment: Drawing it, but if you have a way for uiimageview thats fine too.

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25807455/draw-border-around-content-of-uiimageview

Answer (score 0):

If you want a rounded ImageView.

```
UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@""]];
imageView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor; // Apply Color of your choice
imageView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;  // Apply width of your choice
imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 50; // Apply radius of your choice
imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: Nope, not round image. Its non-square image i.e. star, moon etc.