# Colorize a UIImage in Swift

Tags: swift, image-processing, cifilter

I am trying to write an helper function that applies a color mask to a given image. My function has to set all opaque pixels of an image to the same color.

Here is what I have so far :

```
extension UIImage {

    func applyColorMask(color: UIColor, context: CIContext) -> UIImage {

        guard let cgImageInput = self.cgImage else {
            print("applyColorMask: \(self) has no cgImage attribute.")
            return self
        }

        // Throw away existing colors, and fill the non transparent pixels with the input color
        // s.r = dot(s, redVector), s.g = dot(s, greenVector), s.b = dot(s, blueVector), s.a = dot(s, alphaVector)
        // s = s + bias
        let colorFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIColorMatrix")!
        let ciColorInput = CIColor(cgColor: color.cgColor)
        colorFilter.setValue(CIVector(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0, w: 0), forKey: "inputRVector")
        colorFilter.setValue(CIVector(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0, w: 0), forKey: "inputGVector")
        colorFilter.setValue(CIVector(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0, w: 0), forKey: "inputBVector")
        colorFilter.setValue(CIVector(x: 0, y: 0, z: 0, w: 1), forKey: "inputAVector")
        colorFilter.setValue(CIVector(x: ciColorInput.red, y: ciColorInput.green, z: ciColorInput.blue, w: 0), forKey: "inputBiasVector")
        colorFilter.setValue(CIImage(cgImage: cgImageInput), forKey: kCIInputImageKey)

        if let cgImageOutput = context.createCGImage(colorFilter.outputImage!, from: colorFilter.outputImage!.extent) {
            return UIImage(cgImage: cgImageOutput)
        } else {
            print("applyColorMask: failed to apply filter to \(self)")
            return self
        }
    }
}
```

The code works fine for black and white but not what I expected when applying  funnier colors. See the original image and the screenshots below: the same color is used for the border and for the image. Though they're different. My function is doing wrong. Did I miss something in the filter matrix ?

The original image (there's white dot at the center):

[image: Original pictures]

From top to bottom: The image filtered with `UIColor(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0)` inserted into a UIImageView which has borders of the same color. Then the same with `UIColor(0.6, 0.5, 0.4, 1.0)`. And finally with `UIColor(0.2, 0.5, 1.0, 1.0)`

[image: Screenshot]

---

**EDIT**

Running [Filterpedia](https://github.com/rhoeper/Filterpedia-Swift4) gives me the same result. My understanding of the CIColorMatrix filter may be wrong then. The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/filter/ci/CIColorMatrix) says:

> This filter performs a matrix multiplication, as follows, to transform
>   the color vector:
>
> - s.r = dot(s, redVector)
> - s.g = dot(s, greenVector)
> - s.b = dot(s, blueVector)
> - s.a = dot(s, alphaVector)
> - s = s + bias

Then, let say I throw up all RGB data with (0,0,0,0) vectros, and then pass (0.5, 0, 0, 0) mid-red as the bias vector; I would expect my image to have all its fully opaque pixels to (127, 0, 0). The screenshots below shows that it is slightly lighter (red=186):

[image: Fliterpedia screenshot]

Here is some pseudo code I want to do:

```
// image "im" is a vector of pixels
// pixel "p" is struct of rgba values
// color "col" is the input color or a struct of rgba values
for (p in im) {
    p.r = col.r
    p.g = col.g
    p.b = col.b
    // Nothing to do with the alpha channel
}
```

Comment: If you set your vectors (x:y:z:w:) to: `1,0,0,0` for red, `0,1,0,0` for green, and `0,0,1,0` for blue, you get a normal looking picture. Now, to reduce the red channel by half, set `inputRVector` to `0.5,0,0,0`. To remove *all* red set it to `0,0,0,0`. That's basically how I use it. I'm sure there's other combinations to get other results, but that should get you started.

Comment: Here's a Swift 4 version of Filterpedia - https://github.com/rhoeper/Filterpedia-Swift4 I haven't tried it yet (I have my own Swift 4 port) but it's a great resource for trying out each filter. All input parameters are exposed as `UISliders`, displaying you the min/max/current values. If it's like the original version, there's six different test images along with a few dozen custom filters using either Metal or CIKernel (that use GLSL). One caveat: it's meant to run on iPad only (you can use the simulator but like any CoreImage projects the performance is very poor).

Comment: Thank you for the link @dfd, I tried first to set the rgb vectors to (theRedlwant,0,0,0) (0,theBluelwant,0,0) and (0,0,theGreenIWant,0) but as you said the 1 is use to get a normal looking picture. My goal is to throw away all the color information and get it monochromatic. Just keeping the alpha channel. It will be mostly use to re-colorize buttons images or logos.

Comment: I'll try it the link on my iPad, or on the simulator. I also think there must be another combination.

Comment: Are you trying to end up with a greyscale image? If so, you may get what you want with another "pre-configured" filter like `CIPhotoProcessingMono`. Also, if you know how to write/consume a `CIColorKernel`, I can give you the GLSL code for that. It's pretty simple - 4 lines of code wrapped around a `kernel vec4` function.

Comment: I tried Filterpedia, but the result is the same, the output image is always slightly lighter than expected. I will edited my question with a screenshot.

Comment: The color is important, thus I do not want greyscale. The inputs of my function are the image itself and the color. But it could be interessant to make my image grayscaled first and then colorize it. I don't know how to a CIColorKernel yet but I can explain what I aim to do with a very simple pseudo code (pixel by pixel).

Comment: Ok, I think I understand. You want to take an image pixel-by-pixel and (at least in your example) change each RGB channel. For instance, let's say a pixel has the RGB value of (1.0, 0.4, 0.4) - I have no idea what the color is! - and you pass in a 'col' of (0.5, 0.0, 0.0). You want the output to be R=1.0*0.5, G=0.4*0.0, B=0.4*0.0, yielding (0.5, 0.0, 0.0). Keep in mind, UIKit uses 0-254 but CoreImage uses 0-1. That's a pretty simple `CIColorKernel`. If I'm correct in what you want, let me know an I'll write up the Swift code to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally wrote a CIColorKernel, as @dfd suggested and it works fine:

```
class ColorFilter: CIFilter {

    var inputImage: CIImage?
    var inputColor: CIColor?

    let kernel: CIColorKernel = {
        let kernelString = "kernel vec4 colorize(__sample pixel, vec4 color)\n"
            + "{\n"
            + "    pixel.rgb = color.rgb;\n"
            + "    return pixel;\n"
            + "}\n"

        return CIColorKernel(source: kernelString)!
    }()

    override var outputImage: CIImage? {

        guard let inputImage = inputImage else {
            print("\(self) cannot produce output because no input image provided.")
            return nil
        }
        guard let inputColor = inputColor else {
            print("\(self) cannot produce output because no input color provided.")
            return nil
        }

        let inputs = [inputImage, inputColor] as [Any]
        return kernel.apply(extent: inputImage.extent, arguments: inputs)
    }
}
```

---

To summarize, the CIColorMatrix I used first seems not to be linear (when using the bias vector). Giving a red 0,5 (float) value did not output an image with red 127 color in the [0-255] interval.

Writing a custom filter was my solution.

Answer (score 1):

Glad to have helped. If I may, one thing. You *can* send a color into a kernel - it's a `vec4`, with the fourth value being the alpha channel. Just remember that CoreImage uses 0-1, not 0-254.

Here's the kernel code:

```
kernel vec4 colorize(__sample pixel, vec4 color) {
    pixel.rgb = color.rgb;
    return pixel;
}
```

It's pretty much the same as your's. But now all you need to do is create a `CIColor` instead of an image. If you already have a UIColor called `inputColor`, just do this:

```
let ciColor = CIColor(color: inputColor)
var inputs = [inputImage, ciColor] as [Any]
```

A couple of FYIs.

- There's also a `vec3` that can be used but since you already have a `UIColor` `vec4 looks to be the easiest way.
- `__sample` is the value of the pixel being processed, so it's "base type" is really a `vec4`.

Comment: Thank you ! indeed, making a whole image is a bit extra, so far I've only wrote OpenGL GLSL shaders bound with C++, so I was not sure. I'll update my answer with a simple vec4 !