# UIPageControl dot border color

Tags: ios, objective-c

I’m unable to set the border color of the page control dot in iOS 14. The following code works with iOS < 14, but not with iOS 14:

```c
for (int i = 0; i < [self.subViews count]; i++) {
    UIView *dot = [self.subViews objectAtIndex:i];
    dot.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    dot.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blueColor].CGColor;
}
```

UIPageControl tint color is clear. I just want to add the border only. Need a solution for this in Obj-C.

Answer (score 5):

## Comments

- iOS 14 is still beta and any view hierarchy based solution can stop working with the next beta release.
- It can also stop working in any future iOS release (not beta).
- You're relying on a private view hierarchy. Apple can change it anytime without any further notice. IOW it belongs to the private API usage category = you're on your own here.

## UIPageControl view hierarchy

### iOS 13

[image]

### iOS 14

[image]

## New API

Even if you update your code to match the new view hierarchy ...

```c
UIView *pageControlContentView = self.pageControl.subviews[0];
UIView *pageControlIndicatorContentView = pageControlContentView.subviews[0];
[pageControlIndicatorContentView.subviews enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(__kindof UIView * _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    obj.layer.borderWidth = 1;
    obj.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blueColor.CGColor;
}];
```

... you'll get something like this:

[image]

iOS 14 introduced new properties and methods you can use:

- [`preferredIndicatorImage`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipagecontrol/3577679-preferredindicatorimage?language=objc)
- [`setIndicatorImage(_:forPage:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipagecontrol/3577680-setindicatorimage)
- [`indicatorImageForPage:`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipagecontrol/3577677-indicatorimageforpage?language=objc)

You can use SF Symbols for example:

```c
UIImage *image = [UIImage systemImageNamed:@"link.circle.fill"];
self.pageControl.preferredIndicatorImage = image;
```

Then you'll get:

[image]

In other words, to be safe, avoid private view hierarchies, use `preferredIndicatorImage`. You can prepare your own images if you'd like to customize them, etc. But it's a topic for another question. If you'd like to do it programmatically, search for questions [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47900243/how-to-add-colored-border-to-uiimage-in-swift?rq=1).

Since you're using private view hierarchy, learn your tools (Xcode) and start with the [Examining the View Hierarchy](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/ExaminingtheViewHierarchy.html) and [Debugging View Hierarchies](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/debugging_with_xcode/chapters/special_debugging_workflows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015022-CH9-SW2) chapters. You'll be able to find yourself what's the problem next time.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I only found this like "solution"

Before (< iOS 14):

[image: Before]

After (iOS 14):

[image]

```
if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
            pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = .blue // custom color
            pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = .blue.withAlphaComponent(0.3)
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
            for index: Int in 0...3 {
                guard pageControl.subviews.count > index else { return }
                let dot: UIView = pageControl.subviews[index]
                dot.layer.cornerRadius = dot.frame.size.height / 2
                if index == pageControl.currentPage {
                    dot.backgroundColor = .blue                        
                    dot.layer.borderWidth = 0
                } else {
                    dot.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
                    dot.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
                    dot.layer.borderWidth = 1
                }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The iOS 14 allows setting indicator image with SFSymbol so you're able to use circle.fill and simple circle symbols as dots.

```
func updateBorderColor() {
if #available(iOS 14.0, *) {
    let smallConfiguration = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: 8.0, weight: .bold)
    let circleFill = UIImage(systemName: "circle.fill", withConfiguration: smallConfiguration)
    let circle = UIImage(systemName: "circle", withConfiguration: smallConfiguration)
    for index in 0..<numberOfPages {
        if index == currentPage {
            setIndicatorImage(circleFill, forPage: index)
        } else {
            setIndicatorImage(circle, forPage: index)
        }
    }
    pageIndicatorTintColor = selectionColor
    } else {
    subviews.enumerated().forEach { index, subview in
        if index != currentPage {
            subview.layer.borderColor = selectionColor.cgColor
            subview.layer.borderWidth = 1
        } else {
            subview.layer.borderWidth = 0
        }
    }
}
```